# Establishing HTTP Connection Failing but HTTPS is working

Tags: centos7

I have this issue which is racking my brain. On my local machine, I experience no issues with connecting to my server, here's where it gets odd...

Google Webmaster Tools is stating google cannot access the robots.txt on the HTTP version of a site, but it can access the HTTPS.
Pingdom cannot connect at all to the HTTP version, but it experiences no issues with the HTTPS.
Not to mention Site24x7.com cannot connect to the HTTP of said server with any of it's nodes, but it has no issues with the HTTPS. (https://www.site24x7.com/check-website-availability.html)

I have looked through the error_logs, ssl_error_logs, access_log, ssl_access_log, and there is absolutely nothing. I have also checked all the firewall rules on the server and flushed the deny table (with a full restart of that service), I have also gone through the applicable HTACCESS file and verified it is working correctly.

Anyone have any ideas what might be causing this? The server is running WHM + cPanel Latest.

Please refer to the following website if running any tests;
-Link Removed-

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
root@[~]# telnet psychic.com.au 443 

Trying 198.57.187.236... 
Connected to psychic.com.au. Escape character is '^]'.

root@[~]# telnet psychic.com.au 80 

Trying 198.57.187.236...


root@[~]# telnet psychic.com.au 804  (random port) 

Trying 198.57.187.236...
```

It is some firewall issue. Please check firewall settings.

Comment: I found out that ConfigServer was causing this issue. Thanks for your help! Oddly enough, it wasn't testable from my workstation, or my server pool. :/